# Jquery traversing a table (Error: Not a function)

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

```
$(function(){
  $('.swaction').click(function(event){
    var num = $(this).parent().parent().children().first().children.first().val();
    alert(num);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
})

<table class="table-a" id="unrecognizedPDF">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre de archivo</th>
      <th>Fecha de creación</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>12313242122333</td>
   <td>07/06/2013 10:52:52</td>
   <td><a href="#" data-action="ver" class="swaction">Ver</a> |
       <a href="#" data-action="renombrar" class="swaction">Renombrar</a> |
       <a href="#" data-action="ver" class="swaction">Eliminar</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

I want to get this number: 12313242122333

I tried this: var num =

> $(this).parent().parent().children().first().children.first().val();

but Firebug says it's not a function. Any clue on what is wrong? This is the first time I try to traverse the tree.

Thanks!

Error:

```
TypeError: $(...).parent(...).parent(...).children(...).first(...).children.first is not a function
http://192.168.100.196/printbox/js/js_procesar_escaneos.js
Line 3
```

Comment: Firebug says what's not a function? What's the actual message? Are you remembering to include jQuery?

Comment: Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/uVmRr/ - you had an extra `.children().first()` which wasn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `var num = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();` instead.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DrJhC/)**

`.val()` is for input elements, you want to get the HTML which you'd use `.html()` for.

Comment: It works, but could you explain why my way doesn't work? Reading the documentation seems that it is well done... or at least should work.. putting .html() at the end gives me the same error.

Comment: perhaps it's where you wrote `.children` without the `()` that turns it into a function call?

Comment: Your way could work but you have one too many `.children().first()` selectors (and again, a `val()` instead of `html()`). For example, this works: `$(this).parent().parent().children().first().html();`

Comment: Oh I see, I was traversing one more time than needed (and the error with () ). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use .val() on td element, it's for form element. try .text()

```
$(this).parent().parent().children().first().text();
```

Comment: Hi, tried it:

TypeError: $(...).parent(...).parent(...).children(...).first(...).children.first is not a function
http://192.168.100.196/printbox/js/js_procesar_escaneos.js
Line 3

Comment: as @joe commented, one parent().children() to much, edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
children.first()
```

You're trying to call the `first()` method of the `children` **function**.

You need to *call* the `children` function using parentheses.

Comment: That, and the fact that he used one too many `.children().first()` selectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
```

Try this.

Use `html` instead of `val`